# shut down linux server and turn on automatically at specific time

Tags: command-line, server, shutdown, cron, rtc

I'm having an assignment where the lecturer is asking me to create a bash script to shut down a server at 11pm and turn it on at 6am. I'm able to do it by using `sudo shutdown -h 23:00` and it works. But the problem is that I have no idea how to turn it on automatically on 6am, I couldn't find any commands that could do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your assignment asks you to turn off the whole machine (and back on again), or just one server process? Obivously, the physical machine needs to be switched on to do anything.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea too, I also thought this would be impossible. The lecturer is being very vague on the assignment brief and its driving me nuts as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to check if you can use the [RTC wakealarm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTC_Alarm) to wake your system:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 3 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Now check:

```
cat /proc/driver/rtc
```

This should return a list of parameters. Check the `alrm_time` is 3 minutes into the future and the `alrm_date` is today.

If it works ok, create a `/usr/local/sbin/shutwake` script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 7 hours'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
shutdown -h now
```

Finally edit your user [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/crontab.5.html), type `crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
0 23 * * * /usr/local/sbin/shutwake
```

Comment: I depends on BIOS clock settings, check `/etc/default/rcS` to see if UTC is set or not.

Comment: Well, I tried exactly the same what you wrote above. It didn't worked:(. -Debian 8